# How to read js-year-calendar library(Cannot read property 'classList' of null)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Regarding to the document below,I set up js-year-calendar.

https://github.com/year-calendar/js-year-calendar

by reading such document,I tried to read some files

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/js-year-calendar@latest/dist/js-year-calendar.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/js-year-calendar@latest/dist/js-year-calendar.min.css" />
```

but I suffered like below.How can I fix it ? if you have any idea, please let me know.

```
js-year-calendar.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at new D (js-year-calendar.min.js:1)
```

The error point is below (from js-year-calendar.js)

```
this.element.classList.add('calendar');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your CSS file before JavaScript file.  If it's still not work add data attribute with class like below.

```
<div class='calendar' data-provide="calendar"></div>
```

Run snippet to see working demo.

```js
new Calendar('.calendar');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/js-year-calendar@latest/dist/js-year-calendar.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/js-year-calendar@latest/dist/js-year-calendar.min.js"></script>

<div class='calendar'></div>
```